# Cannot display AR content/object using aframe

Tags: aframe

I'm doing AR using `aframe`. I'm adding more marker and AR contents for my project, but suddenly it shows an error as show in this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeLhu.png).

Can someone assist me on how to rectify the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean suddenly? Do you mean it was working, then stoped working?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an issue specifically with the [AR.js](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js) repository. I would suggest opening an issue on their repository with more information about the specific code you're running (there is not enough information in your question to help solve the problem).

Comment: thank you Kieran, I've post the question to ar.js repository. hope someone can advice me the solution